# How to create a javascript function to go back to the previous modal?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, modal-dialog

I have a series of multiple modals in which there are some forms.

I want to be able to click the "Go Back" button and be on the previous modal. How can this be done without data target?
I would like to create a function as I have way more modals than in the example code below. I tried the `back()` function, but it only works for the browser and not the last modal.

*There are supposed to be more modals (services) to choose from the first modal but i deleted them, as it is for a school project and I can't share the full code.*

Code:

```
<!-- Modal 1 -->
<div class="modal fade" id="modalChoice" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel"
     aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header text-center">
                <h4 class="modal-title w-100 font-weight-bold">Choose a service: </h4>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body btn-group btn-block">
                <div class="md-form" style="margin-left: 70px;margin-top: 20px;">
                    <button data-target="#modal1" data-toggle="modal" data-dismiss="modal" class="button button-form">Service 1</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- End Modal 1 -->



<!-- Modal 2 -->
<div id="Forms" ng-controller="AllForms">
    <form id="Form1" name="Form1" class="form">
        <div class="modal fade" id="modal1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header text-center">
                        <h4 class="modal-title w-100 font-weight-bold">Serv1</h4>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body btn-group btn-block">
                        <div class="modal-body mx-3">
                            <h5 class="font-weight-bold w-100">Owner Info </h5>
                                <div class="md-form mb-3">
                                    <i class="fas fa-user prefix grey-text"></i><label data-error="wrong" data-success="right" for="FormVax1.name" style="padding-left: 5px">Name: </label>
                                    <input id="FormVax1.name" name="name" ng-model="FormVax1.name" class="form-control" required />
                                </div>
                                <div class="md-form mb-3">
                                    <i class="fas fa-location-arrow prefix grey-text"></i><label data-error="wrong" data-success="right" for="FormVax1.address" style="padding-left: 5px">Phone: </label>
                                    <input id="FormVax1.address" name="address" ng-model="FormVax1.address" class="form-control" required />
                                </div>
                                <div class="justify-content-center text-center">
                                    <button data-toggle="modal" data-dismiss="modal" class="button button-form" style="margin:auto;display: inline-block;">Back</button>
                                    <button data-target="#" data-toggle="modal" class="button button-form" style="margin:auto;display: inline-block;">Send</button>
                                </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: Looks like you are using an old version of Bootstrap based on the class names.  If you upgrade to v5 it supports [Toggling between modals](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/modal/#toggle-between-modals) . Also, please explain why the solution needs to "be done without data target".

Comment: Thank you for that! Let me explain, I have 4 choice of services and on each services they are forms. Lets say in service 1 there is the first part of the form where you enter your personal info and there is also a next step where you enter the info of your child and more and more options to enter info. The goal is to make a javascript that reads the last modal that the user was and when I click the Back button, it goes to the previous modal in which I was. Im not allowed to use data target as It is not permitted in the project (to make it tricky I guess?). Do you have any solutions? Thanks :D